# Cracking a 5 digit password

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, password

A gang of thieves has discovered that the 5 digit combination to a safe is even and has exactly one odd
digit and exactly two digits equal to each other. How many possible combinations are there for them to
try?

Comment: this is middle school probability question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> $7200$

Argument:

- There are four possible parity patterns for the combination (o=odd, e=even):
  $oeeee$, $eoeee$, $eeoee$, and $eeeoe$.
- Every parity pattern contains four even digits, of which two must be equal to each other. This gives ${4\choose2}=6$ possibilities for picking the two equal positions.
- Once we have fixed the parity pattern and the two positions with equal digits, there remain five possibilities for the odd digit ($1,3,5,7,9$) and $5\cdot4\cdot3=60$ possibilities for fixing the three distinct even digits ($5$ possibilities for the leftmost even digit, $4$ for the next, and $3$ for the last.)

Altogether, this yields $4\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 60=7200$ possible combinations (out of $100,000$ combinations overall with five digits).

Comment: You're hiding something shifty when you say "5 possibilities for the leftmost even digit."  I'm quite certain you're mistaken; the way you're counting the "two equal positions" vs. the way you pick "three **distinct** even numbers" is miscounting something.  I'm having trouble putting my finger on it though.

Comment: @Wildcard Remember to fix the parity pattern **and** the position of the equal digits before doing it. There is no miscounting.